# get the file location when open applicaiton

Tags: c#, wpf, file

I created an WPF application the use a viewer for file I set the application as default application for this application (filename.myapp), now if I try to open the file it will start the application but I need to know how to get this file location and name so I can use it in the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you want to know the name of the file that was double-clicked/opened with your application associated.

It is the second item in the args array of your start up event:

```cs
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    ...    
    if(e.Args.Length > 1)
    {
        var filename = e.Args[1]);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: tone correction the file name is the 2nd item on args.

Comment: You're right. First item is the application itself. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in the end:

```cs
var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
if (args.Length > 1)
{
    var fileName= args[1];
}
```